# Compatibility issue with Scala and Spark for compiled jars

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, compatibility

I am quite new to Scala and Spark. I had some error with version issue in Scala so I tried to change the Scala version in `pom.xml` in order to run my jar file on the cluster. Finally, I found that the successful Scala version that made the jar run was `2.11`.

However, I am a little bit curious about the Scala version because my Scala version installed on my cluster was 2.10.4 when I commanded `scala -version` on the bash shell (It is not `2.11`). What's even stranger thing is that the jar file didn't work when I changed the scala version `2.11` to `2.10` in `pom.xml` to make the same scala version. And, it throw the error as below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaMirrors$JavaMirror;
        at com.bistel.scala.App$.main(App.scala:17)
        at com.bistel.scala.App.main(App.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

When I changed the scala version to `2.11`, it worked well again and didn't throw any errors. 
I want to understand the compatibility with the Spark and Scala but the above mismatched issues make me confused.

Any help will be appreciated.

I attched the two versions of `pom.xml` (first one is scala version of `2.11` and the other is `2.10`).

Below is the one that work well. Its scala version is 2.11 as indicated.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.bistel.scala</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-001</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
  <description>My wonderfull scala app</description>
  <inceptionYear>2015</inceptionYear>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>My License</name>
      <url>http://....</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
    <scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
          <version>${scala.version}</version>
      </dependency>


      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.1</version>
      </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs2-junit_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.16</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs2-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.16</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <args>
                <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
              </args>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <useFile>false</useFile>
          <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
          <!-- If you have classpath issue like NoDefClassError,... -->
          <!-- useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar -->
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.*</include>
            <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Below is the one that didn't work. Its scala version is 2.10 as indicated.

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.bistel.scala</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-001</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
  <description>My wonderfull scala app</description>
  <inceptionYear>2015</inceptionYear>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>My License</name>
      <url>http://....</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.version>2.10.4</scala.version>
    <scala.compat.version>2.10</scala.compat.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.1</version>
      </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs2-junit_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.16</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs2-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.16</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <args>
                <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
              </args>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <useFile>false</useFile>
          <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
          <!-- If you have classpath issue like NoDefClassError,... -->
          <!-- useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar -->
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.*</include>
            <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several elements which need to be compatible:
1. The version of spark on your driver (and the executors if you are not using yarn to distribute the jars)
2. The version of spark in your pom
3. The version of scala in your source

1) **Version of spark on your driver (+ executors)**: Basically you have some version of spark installed. This spark version is compiled with some scala version (the default for spark 2.X.X is scala 2.11).
It doesn't matter what scala version is installed on the cluster, just what is included in the spark jars.
The same version of spark should be installed on all nodes of the cluster (yarn allows to distribute these jars when you run a new application so in that case you can have multiple versions of spark running together).

2) **Version of spark in your pom:** When you create your pom, you include some dependencies including spark. These have _2.10 or _2.11 appended to their end which represents the version of scala these dependencies match. The spark version can be different that the installed one as spark has backward compatibility (at least in major version) so you can use spark version 2.0.1 in your pom even though your cluster has 2.1.0 (although the other way around is not guaranteed). The scala version must be the same as the version of the installed spark.

3) Lastly, you have **the scala version used for compilation**. This again should be the same as the scala version of spark.

You should also probably set the scope of your spark dependencies as provided to avoid conflicts with the installed version.

Answer (score 1):

You are using spark 2.0.1. In the spark download site:http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html, it is mentioned that

> Starting version 2.0, Spark is built with Scala 2.11 by default. Scala 2.10 users should download the Spark source package and build with Scala 2.10 support.

What is the version of spark in your cluster?
You can try installing spark 2.0.1 and scala 2.11 in cluster. That might help.