# Do we need any external jar for xml parsing in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to parse XML in Spark. i am getting below error. Could you please help me?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object TestSpark{
 def main(args:Array[String})
 {
 val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test")
 val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
 val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
 val df = sqlContext.read
 .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
 .option("rootTag", "book") 
 load("c:\\sample.xml")
 }
}`
```

Error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class for data source: com.databricks.spark.xml.`

Answer (score 2):

No other external jar are required except the [databricks spark xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml). You need to add dependency for 2.0+. If you are using older Spark then you need t use [this](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/tree/branch-0.3).

You need to use

```
groupId: com.databricks
artifactId: spark-xml_2.11
version: 0.4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Match the Scala version to that of Spark. Starting version 2.0, Spark is built with Scala 2.11 by default. Scala 2.10 users should need the Spark source package and build with Scala 2.10 support.
This may help

[Compatibility issue with Scala and Spark for compiled jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082900/compatibility-issue-with-scala-and-spark-for-compiled-jars) 
[spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml)